# What is the difference between application context and workbench context in eclipse e4?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have read in different tutorials/articles these terms are used alternatively 'Application Context' and 'Workbench Context'.

Are they the same? If not, what is the difference between the two? and whats the relationship between them?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the 'Workbench Context' usage?

Comment: Yes, here is the link: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/eclipse-4-e4-tutorial-part-4-dependency-injection-basics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referenced tutorial is using 'Workbench Context' to mean the same thing as the 'Application Context'.